# Queries related to jQuery UI Sortable connected list. Clone Item only once

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two connected lists - Child list and Parent list.
Child list will always be a subset of the parent list.

Below are the two requirements for which I need help:

1. I want to copy data from parent list to child list. Ideally, the
   item    should get cloned when I drag them from parent list to child
   list. Currently, it is moving the item. Also, one item should be
   cloned    only once. No duplicate allowed in child list.
2. I have
   added a delete    functionality in the child list. So whenever a new
   item is added from    parent list to child list. It should also have
   delete functionality.    Not sure how to modify the HTML of the
   newly added item.

Below is the link for the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/pdzwyu8r/

Below is my code:

```
   $( function() {
   $( "#sortable1" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable",           
      update: function(event, ui) {         
      var productOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();  
      $("#sort-2").text (productOrder);  
      }           
        }).disableSelection();
  
    
    $( "#sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable"            
    }).disableSelection();
    
  } );
```

I have found a code that clones item only ones but when I integrate it with my code it does not work. Here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/og937wy7/9/) for that:

Any help appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue.
Below is fiddler url:
https://jsfiddle.net/te9g3vqu/15/

and here is my code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Connect lists</title>

</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<style>

     #sortable1, #sortable2 {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 142px;
    min-height: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    
  }
  #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
  } #sortable1, #sortable2 {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 142px;
    min-height: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    
  }
  #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<body>
 <br>  
   
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><h1>My Apps</h1></td><td><h1>All Apps</h1></td><td><h1></h1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td  style="vertical-align: top;">
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable1">
  <li id="1" class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li id="2" class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li id="3" class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li id="4" class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li id="5" class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul></td>
    <td>
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable2">
  <li id="a" class="ui-state-highlight">Item a</li>
  <li id="b" class="ui-state-highlight">Item b</li>
  <li id="c" class="ui-state-highlight">Item c</li>
  <li id="d" class="ui-state-highlight">Item d</li>
  <li id="e" class="ui-state-highlight">Item e</li>
  <li id="f" class="ui-state-highlight">Item f</li>
  <li id="g" class="ui-state-highlight">Item g</li>
  <li id="h" class="ui-state-highlight">Item h</li>
  <li id="i" class="ui-state-highlight">Item i</li>
  <li id="j" class="ui-state-highlight">Item j</li>
</ul></td><td style="vertical-align: top;"><h3>Child List: <span id="sort-1"></span></h3>  

   <h3>Parent list: <span id="sort-2"></span></h3>  
   
    <!--h3>Deleted list: <span id="sort-3"></span></h3-->  </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
 
</body>
<script>

   /**
 * Adds a delete button to given item as child element
 */
function AddDeleteButtonToItem($item) {
    debugger;
  if (!$item.children(".deleteButton").length) {
    //console.log("adding Del button");
    $item.append("<img class='deleteButton' alt='X'>");
  }
}

/**
 * Adds a delete button to each item of a list and binds event handler
 */
function AddDeleteButtonToList($list) {
  // Add the button to each existing item of the list
  $list.children("li").each(function(i, item) {
    AddDeleteButtonToItem($(item));
  });
  // bind delegated click event handler for Delete buttons to list:
  $list.on({
    "click": DeleteMyApp
  }, ".deleteButton");
}

/**
 * Event handler for Delete item button.
 * 'this' is the Element of the Delete button, which must be a child of the item to delete
 */
function DeleteMyApp() {

  var $item = $(this).closest('li');
  var vid = $item.attr('id');
  //console.log("delete id " + vid);
  //the below statement adds the removed app in All Apps
  // $(this).parent().detach().appendTo("#toolbox");
  //save the removed id here
  $item.remove();
  //update the MyApps list after deletion
  var MyAppsSortable = $("#sortable1").sortable('toArray').toString(); 
            //productOrder = $("#sortable1").sortable('toArray').toString(); 
  $("#sort-1").text (MyAppsSortable);  
}
  
    Array.prototype.remove = function() {
    var what, a = arguments, L = a.length, ax;
    while (L && this.length) {
        what = a[--L];
        while ((ax = this.indexOf(what)) !== -1) {
            this.splice(ax, 1);
        }
    }
    return this;
};

  
  $( function() {
  
   var vdeletedItemsArray = [];
   
    $( "#sortable1" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
      //delay: 50,
      //revert: false,
     // revert: true,
      update: function(event, ui) {         
       //var MyAppsSortable = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString(); 
         //console.log("products: " + productOrder);
     var MyAppsSortable = $("#sortable1").sortable('toArray').toString(); 
            //productOrder = $("#sortable1").sortable('toArray').toString(); 
       $("#sort-1").text (MyAppsSortable);  
       //code to save in User Pref 
            },
        receive: function(event, ui) {
        
         var clazz = ui.item.attr('id');
            //alert($('#sortable1 [id=' + clazz+']').length);
            if($('#sortable1 [id=' + clazz+']').length > 1){ 
            //jquery ui removes ids. thats why we use card
                $('#sortable1 [id=' + clazz+']:not(:first)').remove();
                alert('you can not!');            
            }
       // debugger;
       //AddDeleteButtonToItem(ui.item);
       
        //Array of removed items
        var moved = ui.item;
        var vtemp = moved.attr("id")
        for(var i=0;i<vdeletedItemsArray.length;i++)
        {
            vdeletedItemsArray.remove(vtemp);
        }                           
        $("#sort-3").text(vdeletedItemsArray);
    },
    update: function(event, ui){
        // debugger;
       AddDeleteButtonToItem(ui.item);
    }

    }).disableSelection();
    
   
     $( "#sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable1",
     
       //axis: "x",
      //revert: true,
       helper: "clone",
       revert: "true",
      //delay: 50,
       update: function(event, ui) {         
       var AllAppsSortable = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();  
       $("#sort-2").text (AllAppsSortable);  
 
       //code to save in User Pref 
            },
       receive: function(event, ui) {
      //AddDeleteButtonToItem(ui.item);
       var moved = ui.item;
        vdeletedItemsArray.push(moved.attr("id"));
       //alert("Moved" + moved.attr("id"));
                   
      //var productOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
      $("#sort-3").text(vdeletedItemsArray);
      //console.log("products: " + productOrder);
    }

    }).disableSelection();
    
        // Add Delete buttons to existing items of Child List:
       // debugger;
  AddDeleteButtonToList($("#sortable1"));
    
  } );
  
  $("#sortable2 .ui-state-highlight").draggable({
        helper: function(ev, ui) {
          //  debugger;
        //alert($(this).closest('li').outerHTML() + " ASD");
         //console.log("MY------------------------------------------"+$(this) );
         //var temp = $(this).append("<img class='deleteButton' alt='X'>")[0];
         var temp = $(this)[0].outerHTML;
         
         //temp = temp.append("<img class='deleteButton' alt='X'>");
            //return "<span class='helperPick'>"+ $(this).html() +"</span>";
            return temp;
        },
        connectToSortable: "#sortable1"
    });


</script>
</html>
```

Hope it helps someone in need.

Special thanks to Martin Lisowski :)

Answer (score 1):

I can contribute the part 2 "Delete functionality":

1. We add the delete buttons dynamically using `AddDeleteButtonToItem` - this allows adding it when a new item is dropped on the Child List (I have therefore removed your delete buttons from the original HTML).
2. The initial adding of Delete buttons to the Child list is done in `AddDeleteButtonToList` which also binds the event handler that does the actual deleting. I have slightly modified your handler `DeleteMyApp` to use `this` instead of an argument. Note that we bind a so-called *delegated* event handler, which will also automatically handle Delete buttons added at a later time to the list. See https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler
3. To dynamically add Delete button to newly dropped items, we use the sortable's `receive` event handler of the Child List. It is triggered when an item is dropped on that list. https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive
4. I would extract the `productOrder` when the user presses the order button and not attempt to update it in each event handler (unless you want to add another display of the item list or dynamically compute a total etc.). In the latter case you'd need to trigger an update also in the Delete event handler (not done here).
5. I have also added a CSS class `deleteButton`. It serves several purposes:

   1. Styling the button using CSS
   2. Function `AddDeleteButtonToItem` uses it to check for an existing Delete button to avoid adding a second one.
   3. We need a selector anyway for setting up a delegated event handler in `AddDeleteButtonToList`.
   4. Should you change your mind about the HTML for the Delete button you only need to change the `append()` call in  `AddDeleteButtonToItem` and not any other place.

```js
/**
 * Adds a delete button to given item as child element
 */
function AddDeleteButtonToItem($item) {
  if (!$item.children(".deleteButton").length) {
    //console.log("adding Del button");
    $item.append("<img class='deleteButton' alt='X'>");
  }
}

/**
 * Adds a delete button to each item of a list and binds event handler
 */
function AddDeleteButtonToList($list) {
  // Add the button to each existing item of the list
  $list.children("li").each(function(i, item) {
    AddDeleteButtonToItem($(item));
  });
  // bind delegated click event handler for Delete buttons to list:
  $list.on({
    "click": DeleteMyApp
  }, ".deleteButton");
}

/**
 * Event handler for Delete item button.
 * 'this' is the Element of the Delete button, which must be a child of the item to delete
 */
function DeleteMyApp() {
  var $item = $(this).closest('li');
  var vid = $item.attr('id');
  console.log("delete id " + vid);
  //save the removed id here
  $item.remove();
}


$(function() {
  $("#sortable1").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    update: function(event, ui) {
      var productOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
      $("#sort-2").text(productOrder);
    },
    receive: function(event, ui) {
      AddDeleteButtonToItem(ui.item);
      var productOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
      $("#sort-2").text(productOrder);
      //console.log("products: " + productOrder);
    }
  }).disableSelection();


  $("#sortable2").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable1"
  }).disableSelection();

  // Add Delete buttons to existing items of Child List:
  AddDeleteButtonToList($("#sortable1"));

});
```

```css
#sortable1, #sortable2 {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
  }
   .highlight {  
         border: 2px solid crimson;  
         font-weight: bold;  
         font-size: 40px;  
         background-color: gray;  
      } 
      
.deleteButton {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Connect lists</title>
 
</head>
<body>
 
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable1">
<h1>Child List</h1>
  <li id="1" class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li id="2" class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li id="3" class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li id="4" class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li id="5" class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>
 
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable2">
<h1>Parent List</h1>
  <li id="a" class="ui-state-highlight">Item a</li>
  <li id="b" class="ui-state-highlight">Item b</li>
  <li id="c" class="ui-state-highlight">Item c</li>
  <li id="d" class="ui-state-highlight">Item d</li>
  <li id="e" class="ui-state-highlight">Item e</li>
</ul>
  <br>  
   <h3><span id="sort-2"></span></h3>  
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Martin, your detailed answer and explanation too. That solves half of my problem statement. How can I update my delete function to update the array of list with the deleted record? I asking about point number 4 that you mentioned. Any idea on how to clone item only once?

Comment: productOrder = $("#sortable1").sortable('toArray').toString();

Comment: Don't know how to clone instead of move, sorry.